# Partial triggering from ADF pages is taking long time

Tags: jsf, binding, oracle-adf

I am working on a ADF application which has a lot of jspx pages. Each jspx page was built with lot of UI components binding to viewscoped managed bean.

Structure of jspx page is like

```
<jsp:root>
 <f:view>
 <af:document>
  <af:form>
   <af:panelgrouplayout>
    <af:paneltabbed>
     <af:showdetailitem>
      <af:table>
```

And a few UI components(popups,outputtexts,inputtexts etc) inside panelgrouplayout.

My problem is whenever I made a partial page request most of UI components setter methods are getting invoked in managed bean. It seems entire UI View root is reconstructing for every partial request.

For Eg: value change listener on table - Before calling the exact value change event method most of the UI components setter methods are getting triggered (More than once). Restore view and render response phases are taking more time compared to exact business logic.

I already checked from few questions in stackoverflow that binding of components has to be avoided or at least should not bind to any scope more than request/backingbean. For that I have to do lot of refactoring. How can I improve the performance of partial page request?

Comment: Can you explain how do you apply partial refresh, what is the trigger and which of the components are getting refreshed?